# How to fetch results from a query using fetchall_arrayref in perl?

Tags: perl, dbi

My code:

```
my $sql_query = "select Event_datetime,Event,User from logs";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_query);
$sth->execute();
$testResults = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
foreach my $row (@$testResults) {
    ($Event_datetime,$Event,$User) = @$row;
    print $query->h2($ID);
}
```

I would like to use a for loop to fetch the results of this query(once it is executed) such that each row has a number, i.e. since rows are listed sequentially, I need to access the row by its row number.

i.e. row 1 is 0; row 2 is 1; row 3 is 2 and so on...

for example:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $noOfRows; $i=$i+1) {
    ($ID,$Event_datetime,$Event,$User) = @$testResults;
    print $query->h3($ID, ' ,', $Event_datetime, ',', $Event, ',', $User );
}
```

However, this query does not give me any output. How do I access a particular row by its row number ?

Comment: Add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the top of your file.  You are not showing a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can see also [Perl How to get the index of last element of array reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975837/perl-how-to-get-the-index-of-last-element-of-array-reference)

```
my $lastRowIdx = $#$testResults;
for (my $i=0 ; $i<=$lastRowIdx ; $i++ ) {
  my $rref = $testResults->[$i];
  print "@$rref\n";
} # endfor;
```